# How much memory is allocated to different data types in Javascript & Python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I wanted to know how much memory does different data types take up in Python and Javascript.I know that you do not need to declare types in both the languages but don't forget they are ***dynamically*** typed languages

Comment: This is a good ask, but you may have more luck getting answers if you break it up into two questions, one for each language.

Also, I think you'll find the answers are VERY implementation dependent (especially with JS).

Comment: The problem is it would take more time posting two questions since I would have to wait two days in order to post another question so I just posted it in one and the other reason is since i also wanted an effective comparison.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I still think it's a fine question (I +1'd) just thought you'd have an easier time getting answers with separate ones.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions sir I would try to implement these suggestions in my future question.

Comment: in JS, it depends on how the type is used. for example, an array of ints is an array of ints, until it needs a `null` or `String` element and it's de-optimized into a boxed type that uses doubles for the numbers and 2-byte chars for the string. In JS, Dates and Booleans are Numbers, which are doubles. RegExps vary widely, typed arrays need no explanation. did i forget anything?

Comment: Sir what do you mean by boxed type can u explain it any further it is appearing slightly enigmatic to me

Comment: As a start, for the currently (probably) most common javascript implementations the primitive types would follow what's in the [ES5: Section 8](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.1) specifications, I don't believe there are differences in ES6... but I haven't checked. Section 8 talks about objects, but as @dandavis mentioned, it's not necessarily the same for every object

Comment: a boxed type is an un-optimized way of storing composite objects. it's an early way, the same basic kind used by interpreters instead of JIT engines. it's basically a bunch of pointers and getter methods, compared to a true numerical array (C-like) that occupies a continuous section of RAM and is used by the compiled JS when possible. watch some V8 optimization videos for an overview

Comment: Hi guys your answers were amazing and helped me a  lot but I guess you all missed the part of python plz help me out if you  all know any answer .

Comment: @SuyashSrivastava I've added an analysis on python below. If you find it useful, accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of `Python 3`, let's explore the the amount of storage each of the basic data types consume,

First, let's define a helper function `sizeof` which will help us explore,

```
import sys
def sizeof(x):
    print(x.__class__, sys.getsizeof(x), x)
```

Running this with 64-bit Python 3.6.1, here are the results :

```
>>> sizeof(None)
<class 'NoneType'> 16 None
```

`None` takes 16 bytes. Next let's explore integers,

```
>>> sizeof(10)
<class 'int'> 28 10
>>> sizeof(2**64)
<class 'int'> 36 18446744073709551616
>>> sizeof(2**128)
<class 'int'> 44 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
```

Integers in python are arbitrary precision and the above rightfully exhibits the behaviour, the size grows linearly in the logarithm of the integer represented.

```
>>> sizeof(0.0)
<class 'float'> 24 0.0
>>> sizeof(10.0**100)
<class 'float'> 24 1e+100
>>> sizeof(10.0**308)
<class 'float'> 24 1e+308
```

Floats in python appear to be of constant size (24 bytes)!

```
>>> sizeof("")
<class 'str'> 49 
>>> sizeof("A")
<class 'str'> 50 A
>>> sizeof("AB")
<class 'str'> 51 AB
>>> sizeof("ABC")
<class 'str'> 52 ABC
```

An empty `string` is 49 bytes, it grows linearly with the length of the string.

Next, lets explore lists, dicts, tuples & sets,

```
>>> sizeof([])
<class 'list'> 64 []
>>> sizeof([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
<class 'list'> 144 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

An empty `list` occupies 64 bytes, it grows with the number of elements.

```
>>> sizeof(())
<class 'tuple'> 48 ()
>>> sizeof((1,))
<class 'tuple'> 56 (1,)
>>> sizeof((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,))
<class 'tuple'> 128 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

An empty `tuple` occupies 48 bytes, it grows with the number of elements.

```
>>> sizeof({})
<class 'dict'> 240 {}
>>> sizeof({"a" : 1})
<class 'dict'> 240 {'a': 1}
>>> a = {}
>>> for i in range(20): 
...     a[i] = i**2
... 
>>> sizeof(a)
<class 'dict'> 648 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100, 11: 121, 12: 144, 13: 169, 14: 196, 15: 225, 16: 256, 17: 289, 18: 324, 19: 361}
```

An empty `dict` occupies 240 bytes, it grows with the number of elements.

```
>>> sizeof(set())
<class 'set'> 224 set()
>>> sizeof({1})
<class 'set'> 224 {1}
>>> sizeof({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})
<class 'set'> 736 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

An empty `set` occupies 224 bytes, it grows with the number of elements.

This concludes my brief exploration on the memory consumption of various data types in `python`. Memory management in Python is easy—if you just don’t care *but* it proves to be challenge when you scale !

You read more on memory management in Python in the theano docs [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html).

Comment: I think it is a little odd that a set with 10 items is larger than a dictionary with 20 items.

Comment: What's even more surprising is that a `frozenset` of 10 unique elements occupies 1248 bytes of memory, 512 bytes more than a mutable set !